# How to fix "Application Instantiation Error" caused by "JFactory::getApplication('site')" in docker application?

Tags: php, docker, joomla

I am about to move a Joomla application (*Joomla! 3.7.3 Stable*) into a docker environment. Unfortunately causes the *JFactory::getApplication('site')* an *Application Instantiation Error* that I do not receive in a non-docker environment.

The whole error message:

**Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/var/www/html/project/libs/exporter/TCXExporter.php" at line 132.**

[image]

I am running a *php:7.3-apache* image as my base. Once the container is build I install the following PHP extensions with the help of *docker-php-ext-install*:

- mysqli
- pdo
- pdo_mysql

Further I enable *mod_rewrite* by executing *a2enmod rewrite*.

Neither PHP nor apache are logging any errors that would provide further insights. I have compared the PHP extensions on my host machine with the extensions in the docker container, but could not identify a problem there. However I still do not exclude a missing extension as the reason for the error.

I was able to identify the following line of code as the one that causes the failure:

```php
$mainframe = & JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

Comment: You might like to give [joomla.se] Stack Exchange a crack ...because I am hearing crickets on this page.

Comment: True, will do that. Thanks for the tip.